# Send an invitation to a list same app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, sdk

I am pretty new with iOS 5 and I am thinking in writing an app.

I would have a list of people inside the app who has it. Then I would invite them to an event.
I don't need any code right now I just wanted to know the concept behind this.

First, how an app can recognise who has my it installed, so it can show a list of people.
Second, after creating an event with a group of people how can I send an invitation to them.

Thanks

Comment: This question is very broad and general.  Why don't you do some research on tools and design patterns in iOS and try and come up with a design yourself?  It doesn't seem like you've done any research (or at least you haven't shared it with us) and SO does not exist to tell you how to design your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a very general standpoint, what you need is a back-end server to interact with your app and store user/event info. You can either build your own or try to use a service like [Parse](http://www.parse.com).